# How to rip an audio CD into flac

Tags: rhythmbox, cd, cd-ripping, flac

Hello I tried to rip some Audio CDs into the lossless flac format.

Flac has different compression rates and multiple arguments which can be passed. Normally I like to use `flac` with the argument `-V8` which means, that the ripped content is validated and that the highest compression rate is used. Remember: Flac is lossless. So the compression rate influences not the quality. It influences just the processing time and the file size.

I used Rhythmbox and RipperX to rip my Audio CDs.

Well, Rhythmbox can identify the Audio CD and shows the interprets name and all track titles automatically. But it is not possible to edit the ripping format options. It is not possible to adjust the compression level. It uses the default compression level of 5 instead.

So I tried RipperX. In the options menu I can add additional arguments, which are used, when `flac` is called. This good, so I can adjust the compression level. Well, but RipperX cannot identify the Audio CD. It does not show the interprets name and all track titles.

I'm searching for a way to rip my Audio CDs into flac format with the highest compression level and the correct interprets name **and** all track titles. Of course I could use Rhythmbox to rip my Audio CDs into wave and then use `flac` to convert into flac and then delete the old wave files, but I am searching for a way to do both steps at once.

Does anybody know a way to rip an audio CD into flac without my issues?

Comment: Hello mchid. Thank you for your hint. I tried using ripperx. But the files just have standard names like "title 1, title 2 ...) and Rythmbox shows no meta data like artist etc, too.

Comment: Okay, see my answer below. Unlike windows, you don't need to "rip" tracks in linux, just copy and paste because everything in linux (almost everthing) is a file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suggest the application `abcde`. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install abcde flac
```

Now, put the CD into the tray. You might wish to create a directory of music files:

```
mkdir flacs
cd flacs
abcde -o flac
```

In order to get track information, etc., *abcde* queries the CDDB via an internet connection. If there is no internet connection, or if the CD is not registered, no track information will be retieved, although you may manually edit the input. Here is an example of the track information gathered:

```
Grabbing entire CD - tracks: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
Retrieving 1 CDDB match...done.
---- Muddy Waters / The Real Folk Blues ----
1: Mannish Boy
2: Screamin' and Cryin'
3: Just To Be With You
<snip>


Edit selected CDDB data [y/N]?
```

Pressing Enter selects the default, No.

After ripping, a file appears named "Muddy Waters / The Real Folk Blues". Within it are the track listings CDDB found.

```
chili@T440p:~/Desktop/flac$ ls Muddy_Waters-The_Real_Folk_Blues/
01.Mannish_Boy.flac          07.Same_Thing.flac
02.Screamin_and_Cryin.flac   08.Gypsy_Woman.flac
03.Just_To_Be_With_You.flac  09.Rollin_&_Tumblin.flac
04.Walking_in_the_park.flac  10.40_Days_and_Forty_Nights.flac
05.Walking_Blues.flac        11.Little_Geneva.flac
06.Canary_Bird.flac          12.You_Cant_Lose_What_You_Never_Had.flac
```

If the CD is not on file with CDDB, you will have the option to edit the titles and other information and submit it. If there is no internet connection, then you must manually edit the file.

You can set the variables you wish to use by default by creating a conf file:

```
cp /etc/abcde.conf  ~/.abcde.conf
gedit .abcde.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Check for the common variables that you wish to use. Uncomment the settings you'd like to use by default. For example, change:

```
#OUTPUTTYPE=ogg
```

To:

```
OUTPUTTYPE=flac
```

In this example, once you have specified the output type as flac, it is no longer necessary to specify it on the command line. Merely do:

```
abcde
```

Comment: Hello chili555, `abcde` is amazing, because its is powerful lightweight and because of its name! I was able to rip my audio CD into a flac files. Nevertheless there are no track titels. The man page sayes:
`       *      Do a CDDB or Musicbrainz query over the Internet to look up your
              CD or use a locally stored CDDB entry, or read CD-TEXT from your
              CD as a fallback for track information`
- Nevertheless there is no track information shown.

Comment: I suggest you start a new question. I will be happy to help.

Comment: Hey chili555. I edited my question to clarify the problem. I think we should solve the problem here, because there is no new question and this question is not solved. Would you please provide your helping hints by editing your answer?

Comment: Read here & get yourself a .abcde.conf for flac (goes in your home folder http://www.andrews-corner.org/abcde.html

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something more like soundconverter.

To install, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

If you cannot find the application right away in your installed apps, just run the following command to start it up:

```
soundconverter &
```

You should be able to use your favourite file manager to copy and paste the files from your compact-disk to a directory (folder) like your Music directory.

These files should be in wav format when copied from the CD.

Converting from wav to flac should be lossless as flac has more compression than wav.

You can convert the tracks to flac using soundconverter after the files have been copied to your computer.

There is a way to convert tracks using the command-line which allows more control over the parameters; I can post this method if you are interested.

---

If that is not good enough, copy all the wav files to your ~/Music directory and then run the following command in a terminal to convert the files to flac:

```
find ~/Music -type f -iname "*.wav" | while read fn; do flac --keep-foreign-metadata --verify "$fn"; done
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85455/convert-wav-music-library-to-flac-on-command-line-and-achieve-best-quality)

Comment: Hello mchid. Well, I can copy the wav files and then convert it with soundconverter or `flac`. But both programs are not reading the meta data. :-( So there are no artist or track names.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using Asunder, but now I notice even though I specify FLAC output, it saves the files as lossy m4a. What's going on? There's no button that says "Fix this so it works right," so I'm not using it now.
Sound Juicer seems to be a good alternative that is actually saving my tracks as FLAC format. That's what I want.